# Including external scripts with global references using Webpack

Tags: javascript, leaflet, webpack-2

I am working on using Webpack 2 to package some oldish javascript code. This code uses the Leaflet 1.0 library and also includes a Leaflet plugin (named Google.js) that simply references the global `L` variable that leaflet exposes.

In the current html page, leaflet and then the plugin (Google.js) is loaded and then the `map1.js` code via script tags. Which all works fine.

I have created the following `webpack.config.js`:

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  devtool: 'cheap-eval-source-map',
  entry: {
    map1: './js/map1.js'
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  }
};
```

and in the `map1.js` I have added the following to define the dependency requirements for webpack:

```
import bootstrap from 'bootstrap';
import leaflet from 'leaflet';
require('script-loader!./lib/Google.js');
```

The `bundle.js` builds without issue however when the page loads, I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined
    at NewClass.whenReady (eval at  (bundle.js:79), :3641:12)
    at NewClass.addLayer (eval at  (bundle.js:79), :4057:8)
    at eval (eval at  (bundle.js:176), :118:7)
    at eval (eval at  (bundle.js:176), :232:3)
    at Object. (bundle.js:176)
    at __webpack_require__ (bundle.js:20)
    at bundle.js:66
    at bundle.js:69
```

Looking at line 79 where the errors occurs:

`eval("var __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_FACTORY__, __WEBPACK_AMD_DEFINE_RESULT__;/*\n Leaflet 1.0.3, a JS library for interactive maps...`

it appears to failing on doing an eval of the leaflet code. Should I be doing anything else to incorporate Leaflet into my webpack build?

Comment: It looks like is a problem with the source map eval, do you really need the 'cheap-eval-source-map' or can it be any source maps configuration? Have you tried with 'inline-source-map' instead?

Comment: I've removed the `devtool` line in `webpack.config.js`. Same error message unfortunately on a hard refresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried a very simple webpack project using [Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant](https://gitlab.com/IvanSanchez/Leaflet.GridLayer.GoogleMutant) instead, and it works like a charm:

```
import 'leaflet';
import 'leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant';

var map = L.map('map').setView([0,0],0);
var roadMutant = L.gridLayer.googleMutant({                     
  maxZoom: 24,                  
  type:'roadmap'                
}).addTo(map);
```

That will work as long as you reference the GMaps JS API in a separate `<script>` in your HTML. And `npm install leaflet leaflet.gridlayer.googlemutant`, of course.